# How to stop WordPress from sending mails?

Tags: email

I got a big problem with my wordpress instance. I have a directory plugin (sabai) and since this morning wordpress is sending a lot mails to my customers. Since now I don´t know how to fix it, so I want to block WordPress complete from sending mails. Can you tell me how?

Thx a lot!

Comment: What plugin are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

There are several plugins that do this, but bear in mind they will disable wp_mail completely so even password reminders/reset etc will not be sent. [stop email plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/stop-emails/) or [disable plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-emails/)